# How is Forge Networking able to provide unlimited CCU?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, server, unity-networking

I was wondering how Forge Networking could provide **unlimited** CCU for every user, since it is a **one-time** purchase. Is there something about networking I still do not understand or do they simply own a lot of servers?

Comment: As on Unity Answer, I will invite you to contact the [**creator of the Asset**](https://developers.forgepowered.com/) if you have a specific question about the later. People don't necessary know this asset and won't be able to help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking how a particular piece of software achieves a particular task. We did not create the software, and thus, and answer to this question would derive from pure speculation. As already addressed in a previous comment, it is best to contact the original author with such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that Forge Networking doesn't "provide" unlimited CCU - rather, they "allow" it, and ***you*** provide it.

From https://developers.forgepowered.com/, under "What is Forge Networking?":

> You can host servers at no cost with this system. The catch is that you host them all yourself, manage them yourself and so forth.

They also provide tutorials on how to deploy a headless version of your server for self/cloud hosting, here: https://developers.forgepowered.com/Tutorials

I've found no mention anywhere that they provide hosting. I assume they are only mentioning the lack of DAU/CCU limits to address a common question (and, of course, to help sell the asset), not to imply that they are a hosting service without such limits.